# Meta Key Cancels Ctrl in Emacs

Tags: macos, emacs

I am trying to override <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Meta</kbd>-<kbd>Down Arrow</kbd> and <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Meta</kbd>-<kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> in emacs.

I've tried all sorts of combinations of: `(global-set-key [C-M-down] 'function)` and: `"\C-\M-<down>"` etc... but it always says: `ESC undefined`. This means it is only taking into account the `M-<down>`. Why is it ignoring the <kbd>Control</kbd>?? I've been working on this for 3 hours and emacs online documentation with regards to key bindings is surprisingly absolutely terrible.

Comment: *when* does Emacs say `ESC undefined`?  To see what bindings have been made, type `C-h b`, and then you'll see what (if anything) 'function was bound to.  (alternatively `C-h w function`)

Comment: If I hit: `C-h k` then hit `Ctrl-Meta-down`, it says `ESC undefined`. Meaning, it never even got the ctrl key press. Why is that?

Comment: Does it work when you start Emacs without your init-file?

Comment: Can I ask you who got you started using Emacs in a Terminal?  This question and the one about TERM export are the most asked questions here about Emacs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using Emacs in the terminal (which you mentioned in a comment), you are limited to the key sequences that the terminal is capable of. Unfortunately, C-down is not one of them...

Comment: So what sequences is the terminal not capable of? And so what would you recommend to bind `scroll-other-window` and `scroll-other-window-down` to in a logical manner, where `scroll-other-window` scrolls down and `scroll-other-window-down` scrolls up?

Comment: Well, C-c LETTER is reserved for your own bindings, so maybe `C-c p` and `C-c n`?

Answer (score 0):

Some versions of Emacs on Mac OS X have had problems with the qualifier keys. Try to update it to a newer version.

I tested this on an Emacs built from the source archive, and it works as intended. (In this case, it simply says that `function` is not defined, which is what expected.)

Comment: Which distribution? I just tested this on the one from http://emacsformacosx.com/ and it works correctly.

Comment: I am using the terminal based one. That Emacs (I tested it too) works fine. Why doesn't it work with the terminal based Emacs?